# TypeError str object is not callable when use comprehension

Tags: python, for-comprehension

I found similar questions but those did not address my problem.

When I use:
`response = [str(s) if type(s) != list else 0 for s in jsondata[j].values()]`

I get `str object is not callable`

But this works well:
`response = [str(s) for s in jsondata[j].values()]`

I just want fix list alone. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you overwrite `type`? What do you get if you print `type`? `print(type)`

Comment: You most likely assigned a string to a variable named `type` which masks the builtin function `type`. You had a suggestion to fix that 10 minutes ago... have you had a chance to check? We need feedback if we are to help.

Comment: Thinks U are right